cross compile mysql C API on ubuntu 22.04 for windows using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
My mysql C API file links and creates executable on on ubuntu 22.04 using gcc without any problem. When I try to cross compile it using x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc I get several errors, a few are shown below:
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccvgdLNU.o:mysqlchk_lic.c:(.text+0x2b2): undefined reference to mysql_num_fields' /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccvgdLNU.o:mysqlchk_lic.c:(.text+0x2c7): undefined reference to mysql_fetch_row'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccvgdLNU.o:mysqlchk_lic.c:(.text+0x2f5): undefined reference to mysql_free_result' /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: /tmp/ccvgdLNU.o:mysqlchk_lic.c:(.text+0x304): undefined reference to mysql_close'
What am I missing? Thanks in advance.
Girish Joglekar

What command do you use to cross-compile? Did you also cross-compile the library you're using?

Instead of gcc I used x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc. I do not have any libraries of my own, it is just one c file. Do I need cross-compiled C API libraries? I have no idea how to get them.

Yes, any library you use must be compiled with mingw, including this mysql C API.

I installed MySQL 8.0 on my Windows 11 machine. It came with the dlls and .h files, When I compile and link my .c file, it creates an executable but it does not do anything. Are libraries compiled with mingw available anywhere?
